# SpringBoot Application startup failed due to Logback configuration error detected

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

My spring boot project has logback.xml file in the path src/resources/logback.xml. While running the application from IntelliJ, unfortunately, it is finding the logback xml from another project where the project location is entirely different.

This is causing the problem below hence application startup is failed.

```
-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [Another project logback path]

at ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type io.symphonia.lambda.logging.DefaultConsoleAppender
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.symphonia.lambda.logging.DefaultConsoleAppender
...
...
ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type io.symphonia.lambda.logging.DefaultConsoleAppender
...
...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Could not create an Appender of type [io.symphonia.lambda.logging.DefaultConsoleAppender]. ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type io.symphonia.lambda.logging.DefaultConsoleAppender
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@3:84 - ActionException in Action for tag [appender] ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ActionException: ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type io.symphonia.lambda.logging.DefaultConsoleAppender
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Could not find an appender named [STDOUT]. Did you define it below instead of above in the configuration file?
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - See http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#appender_order for more details.
at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:151)
```

Any path settings to be done? I could not get the problem. Please help!

Thanks

Comment: maybe renaming the folder resource to resources would help

Comment: Sorry, The Folder name is resources only. It was a typo mistake. Edited question

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` This error means that your application is trying to load a class that is not present in your classpath, translating it to your project it means you didn't add the correct dependencies (maven/gradle) for the configuration you are using on your logback.xml file.

Comment: Could you post your `src/resources/logback.xml`, maybe the problem is in there.